# Why OSX's strip can not remove weak symbols?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, strip, mach-o

While trying to strip out unneeded things from my linked executable I've found some strange thing.
Assume we have a simple, straightforward C++ program:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename T>
    char* getPtr() {
        static char c;
        return &c;
    }
};

char* bar() {
    Foo i;
    return i.getPtr<int>();
}

int main() {
    bar();
}
```

Binary being built with `clang++ t.cc` has next dynamic symbol table:

```
$ gobjdump -T ./a.out

./a.out:     file format mach-o-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000100000f40 g       0f SECT   01 0000 [.text] __Z3barv
0000000100000f60 g       0f SECT   01 0080 [.text] __ZN3Foo6getPtrIiEEPcv
0000000100001020 g       0f SECT   08 0080 [.data] __ZZN3Foo6getPtrIiEEPcvE1c
0000000100000000 g       0f SECT   01 0010 [.text] __mh_execute_header
0000000100000f80 g       0f SECT   01 0000 [.text] _main
0000000000000000 g       01 UND    00 0200 dyld_stub_binder
```

Considering that it is an executable and not a dylib I would like to strip all entries except those for undefined symbols. Theoretically binary still will work since info about required dyld binding is still there and entry point is defined in some load command after mach-o header (so nothing to do with symbol table).

Trying `strip` gives some weird result:

```
$ strip ./a.out
$ gobjdump -T ./a.out

./a.out:     file format mach-o-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000005614542      d  3c OPT    00 0000 radr://5614542
0000000100000f60 g       0f SECT   01 0080 [.text] __ZN3Foo6getPtrIiEEPcv
0000000100001020 g       0f SECT   08 0080 [.data] __ZZN3Foo6getPtrIiEEPcvE1c
0000000100000000 g       0f SECT   01 0010 [.text] __mh_execute_header
0000000000000000 g       01 UND    00 0200 dyld_stub_binder
```

Last two entries shouldn't be stripped anyway as they are required by dyld to handle this executable. At the same time we see that `_main` and `__Z3barv` are gone. But symbols from `class Foo` are still there. The only difference between them and stripped ones is that former ones have `N_WEAK_DEF` flag set (0080). Here is some scant info from `<mach-o/nlist.h>` about that flag:

```
 /*
 * The N_WEAK_DEF bit of the n_desc field indicates to the static and dynamic
 * linkers that the symbol definition is weak, allowing a non-weak symbol to
 * also be used which causes the weak definition to be discared.  Currently this
 * is only supported for symbols in coalesed sections.
 */
#define N_WEAK_DEF  0x0080 /* coalesed symbol is a weak definition */
```

Unfortunately it doesn't explain why `strip` ignores symbols with that flag.

So the question is - how to teach `strip` to remove even `N_WEAK_DEF` symbols in case user just doesn't want to export them.

P.S. I've looked into command options and haven't found anything useful (`-N` removes undefined symbols too, so it is not an option). Declaring that class with `visibility("hidden")` makes the puzzle, but unfortunately it is not easy to do with the real project.

Comment: Why do you have nlist relocations there and not bytecode relocations? Are you trying to strip an object (`MH_OBJECT`) file? Typically executables and shared libraries are linked by ld64 using a bytecode/compressed relocation format that dyld reads at start instead of nlist-based relocations which are more informative but are not used in final binaries unless explicitly requested.

Comment: @KristinaBrooks what do you mean by relocations? There are only dynamic symbol tables. Executable contains `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` command with rebase and bind info in usual compressed form, but I haven't provide them since they should be irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Your binary has a bytestream that tells dyld how to adjust its position (without it all global variables would not work) as well as performing actual linking. Your binary is generally relocated because of ASLR as a security measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first conclusion would be to jump to it being a result of radar bug 5614542 hence that weird symbol, but it's not related to it.

<strike>I'll draw some assumptions and guess from the fact that it seems that you're using nlist relocations and not new bytecode based relocations (you can check by looking for the  dyld info load command), this is either built with an ancient toolchain or is a `MH_OBJECT` file for a main executable that has not gone through the final linking step. I'm not 100% sure if that is the case here- but either way,</strike>

Sorry for my above assumption, but the original answer still applies unless you use really want to opt out of symbol coalescing in which case build your application with private linkage but again this template instantiation forces the symbol as weak for a very good reason, it has a static constructor and an implicitly instantiated template, it prefers safety so it keeps the symbol. You can not export it at all outside of the executable, while you have a small case here, C++ programs tend to use things like boost, or C++ libs that depend on other C++ libs, that all creates chains and eventually you end up with multiple definitions within the shared namespace just because of C++ semantics. In your small test case you can get away with it, in a larger application unless you really know what you're doing and examining things like dependency trees for dylibs, just let dyld do its job. I think my original answer still applies for a major part as it explains why your symbol is marked as weak (ODR is a C++ specific concept but it's dealt differently by different static linkers):

---

For a longer explanation - it's to do with C++ semantics, namely the **one definition rule** (ODR) which is a close but not the same concept as not being able to have duplicate strong symbols in the same namespace (I mean a link namespace, not an C++ namespace, this gets confusing very quickly).

If you want to know why it's marked as weak, it's for dyld to be able to coalesce it during **dynamic linking**, since reusing that template would instantiate it again (causing an ODR violation and depending on the context a link time error), as it's an implicit instantion, which may or may not require coalescing (which is not known until static or even dynamic link time, unless of course you define it as hidden in which case you have to be extremely careful since semantics will vary a lot depending on factors like whether it's a modular build or not (I mean LLVM "modules", not the Modules TS for C++).

Without it being weak, you'd be causing an ODR violation per C++ rules by defining it as hidden across more than 1 translation unit (if you reused that template, say in a header within the module, you would get duplicate symbol errors). You could get away with violating ODR since it's not actually enforced, but be prepared for some nasty surprises (ie. by using non modular builds aka "every translation unit is a module").

By defining it as weak, dyld is able to select correct definitions per final linked object be that a shared library or an executable (and don't forget about the shared cache) at **runtime** and bind/relocate them appropriately within the otherwise flat namespace.

The above is a lot to be able to deduce by a compiler without any form of a hint, hidden linkage is a really bad idea unless you understand the implication, you want `internal` visibility if you really want to re-instantiate and copy the template every time. OSX has a fairly complicated linking model in general, a lot of landmines to step on potentially.

<s>And if I'm right about the object file thing, **you shouldn't really run strip on object files before they are fed into the static linker**.</s>

Comment: Thanks for response! Unfortunately, file is `MH_EXECUTE`. And it contains both exports in `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` and nlist array as well. But it shouldn't be a problem since any form represents the same interface. I understand your point that linker must see all weak defs that are going into final binary. But my situation is a bit different. My binary is already linked and is loadable, so all possible coalescing should be done already as long as I don't want to expose anything outside of my executable. That is why I'm surprised that strip rejects to remove those unneeded weak def records.

Comment: I revised my answer but it still applies for a large part, coalescing is a part of making sure more complex application with bigger dependencies tree do not end up with duplicate symbols and dyld requires those weak symbols for rebinding, otherwise you would get runtime errors at startup due to duplicate symbols defined in multiple libs.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Apple opensource project I've finally found the answer. It looks like [`strip`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-822/misc/strip.c.auto.html) never removes global weak def symbols:

```
    ...
    *
    * In 64-bit applications, we only need to save coalesced
    * symbols that are used as weak definitions.
    */
    ...
```

(Unfortunately website has no per-line navigation, or maybe I was not looking thoroughly enough)
That explains my case since my binary is `mach-o-x86-64`.

Nevertheless motivation behind this behavior is still unclear.

**EDIT**: See Kristina's answer to have an idea why `strip` prefers to keep global weak definitions.